# How to upload video with our extension on magento connect?

Tags: magento-connect, upload, product-view, video, extensions

You guys are surely familiar with magento connect market place for magento products. You might have seen that there are many products on magento connect have base video rather than base image on their product view page.

I want to know about the process and limitation (if any) of how to uplaod video with our extension on magento connect.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example you can share with us?

Comment: David, many thanks for your reply. Yes, I can show you the example. For that please refer the image that I have recently added to the question.

Comment: Do you have an example from a developer that's not a platinum partner? Or that is not a partner at all? Maybe it's a feature for partners and us mortals don't have access to it.

Comment: yes @Marius there is special features that is only provide for partner.

Comment: Maybe we should summon @benmarks on this. He can get the inside info.

Comment: Does the answer helps? What additional details do you need?

Comment: yes, amasty. I got it. Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Uploading video for extensions in addition to the images is available for older or existing Magento partners (all levels) since Magento Connect update in 2012.

See part of the partners email newsletter:
[image: video for magento connect]

Please contact your partner manager do get detailed instructions regarding the video size, lengths and quality standards.